# How to prevent attributed nested list from splitting the parent?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When having a nested list which is preceded by a `#+ATTR_LATEX`, the parent list is split into two, contrary to the expected result.

In this example the nested list is attributed to make it inline:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{enumitem}

1. 111
2. 222
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment enumerate*
  1. 333
  2. 444
3. 555
```

The desired result in latex-export would be:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 111
\item 222
\begin{enumerate*}
\item 333
\item 444
\end{enumerate*}
\item 555
\end{enumerate}
```

White the actual result is:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 111
\item 222
\end{enumerate}     %undesired%
\begin{enumerate*}
\item 333
\item 444
\end{enumerate*}
\begin{enumerate}   %undesired%
\item 555
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected with proper indentation:

```
1. 111
2. 222
  #+ATTR_LATEX: :environment enumerate*
  1. 333
  2. 444
3. 555
```

Comment: I feel so stupid. (that said, the tabbing scheme in org does tend to be confusing)